# Dynamic population of data based on validation list?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

EDIT: I know I could just populate formulas in a range all the way down for columns G:I, but I know that the list (columns A:C) will grow and I don't want to keep expanding the formula range. I imagine this is only doable in VBA via looping?

I have raw data in columns `A:C`

[image]

Is it possible to select a value to drop down list (cell E2) and have the orange range populate (columns G:I) when Name (column A=E2) and status (column C = Negotiating)?

[image]

I tried to do some research online and couldn't even figure out what keywords to type in. I know I could do something like in tableau, but wanted to see if this was doable in excel?

I tried searching keywords in google, but didn't even know where to start because I'm used to doing things like this in tableau, but not excel.

updated formula not working

```
=LET(
lr,COUNTA('Master Line List - All Data'!L:L),
fRng,'Master Line List - All Data'!L3:INDEX('Master Line List - 
All Data'!M:M,lr),
criteriaRng1,'Master Line List - All Data'!L3:INDEX('Master 
Line List - All Data'!L:L,lr),
criteriaRng2,'Master Line List - All Data'!M3:INDEX('Master 
Line List - All Data'!M:M,lr),
FILTER(fRng,(criteriaRng1=A1)*(criteriaRng2="Denied")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need `FILTER()` function.

```
=FILTER(A2:C9,(A2:A9=E2)*(C2:C9="Negotiating"))
```

[image]

To make filter range dynamic, you may try-

```
=LET(
lr,COUNTA(A:A),
fRng,A2:INDEX(C:C,lr),
criteriaRng1,A2:INDEX(A:A,lr),
criteriaRng2,C2:INDEX(C:C,lr),
FILTER(fRng,(criteriaRng1=E2)*(criteriaRng2="Negotiating")))
```

[image]

Comment: I think I need VBA for this because  the raw data (A:C) will be ever expanding and I do not want to keep adjusting the row counts there. I know I could do A:C,(A:A= etc but then I get a spill erro

Comment: @Kolev_I_N You can do it by formula. Try my second formula.

Comment: So I tried this in my actual data. Column L:L in Master Line List worksheet = the names and column M:M = the statuses. I updated my post at the bottom to reflect my new formula, but I get a #CALC error, any idea why?

Comment: @Kolev_I_N If your data starts from `L3` cell in `L Column` then you need to adjust range. Add 2 to `COUNTA()` formula `lr,COUNTA('Master Line List - All Data'!L:L)+2`.

Answer (score 0):

*There are many ways to work on this, but in terms of **flexibility**, I would use `POWER QUERY` here which can **effortlessly** do the automation thus saving **time and effort**. `Power Query`, available in `Windows Excel 2010+` and `Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)`*. Watch the demonstration for reference. Takes less then **2 minutes** to perform the task.

---

[image]

---

To use Power Query follow the steps:

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Ownertbl`, `NameCon` & `StatusCon` (you can name them as per your choice, only there shouldnt be any space or special characters other than underscore)

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    SourceN = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="NameCon"]}[Content],
    DataTypeN = Table.TransformColumnTypes(SourceN,{{"Select Name", type text}}),
    NameCon = DataTypeN{0}[Select Name],
    
    SourceS = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="StatusCon"]}[Content],
    DataTypeS = Table.TransformColumnTypes(SourceS,{{"Status", type text}}),
    StatusCon = DataTypeS{0}[Status],
    
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Ownertbl"]}[Content],
    DataType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Name", type text}, {"Landowner", type text}, {"Status", type text}}),
    FilterName= Table.SelectRows(DataType, each ([Status] = StatusCon)),
    FilterStatus = Table.SelectRows(FilterName, each ([Name] = NameCon))
in
    FilterStatus
```

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

**Note:** *Quite a large amount of datasets can be handled using `POWER QUERY` without any hassle, this is only a one time approach, i.e. you don't have to increase the range nor you have to write the m-codes every single time a new data is added, only you need to refresh the imported table. As far i see this is the most hassle free and time saving tool.*

---